# Работа с файлами в Си (Подсчет часто повторяющихся слов)

Tags: c

**Задача:** Исходный файл представлен в текстовом формате данных, с разделениями слов пробелами и знаками препинания. Найти 7 наиболее часто встречающихся слов и вывести их число появлений в другом файле.

Вот мой код

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fp_read;
  FILE *fp_out;
  char str[100];
  fp_read = fopen("input.txt","r");
  fgets (str, 100, fp_read);
  printf("%s",str);
  for(int i = 0; i != "\0"; i++)
  {
      if((str[i] == ",") || (str[i] == ".") || (str[i] == "!"))
      {
          printf("lox");
      }
  }


  fclose(fp_read);

    return 0;
}
```

Правда кодом это сложно назвать в нем выдается ошибка и нет идеи как дальше реализовать чтение и разделение с помощю знаков препинаания. Помогите пожалуйста, как решить данную задачу

Comment: `strtok()` и `fprintf()` в помощь.

Comment: Вот подобная задача и её решение. Под свои нужнды можете за вечер поправить. https://pastebin.com/vsQG1bPS Там в шапке накиданы ещё пути улучшения.

Comment: @eanmos, всё же я бы рекомендовал `strsep()`, а то потом будут интересные грабли у новичков.